# Bar Chart Left to right swoop in animation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, apexcharts

I am not able to disable the swoop in left to right animation on multiple bar chart.
I want only the growing (Down to up) animation and disable the swoop in left to right .
And I use ApexChart Library for bar chart.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rcux0.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKAbl.png)

I have been exploring the ApexCharts documentation and tried to modify the animation options, but I couldn't find a way to disable this specific animation. My goal is to display the charts with an animation that only allows the bars to grow vertically. I want to completely disable the horizontal 'swoop' animation.

Comment: I think you can use Column chart instead of bar chart for the animation which you required for reference https://apexcharts.com/react-chart-demos/column-charts/basic/